# Turning tuples into a pairwise string

Tags: python

I have the following tuples

```
[   ('StemCells', 16.530000000000001),
    ('Bcells', 13.59),
    ('Monocytes', 11.58),
    ('abTcells', 10.050000000000001),
    ('Macrophages', 9.6899999999999995),
    ('gdTCells', 9.4900000000000002),
    ('StromalCells', 9.3599999999999994),
    ('DendriticCells', 9.1999999999999993),
    ('NKCells', 7.8099999999999996),
    ('Neutrophils', 2.71)]
```

what I want to create is to create a single string that looks like this:

```
StemCells(16.53), Bcells(13.59), Monocytes(11.58) .... Neutrophils(2.71)
```

How can I do that conveniently in Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
', '.join('%s(%.02f)' % (x, y) for x, y in tuplelist)
```

Comment: Since `str.join` has to turn the iterator into a list (because it passes over it twice), it's actually slightly more performant to pass it a list comprehension. This is the narrow case where I'd use a list comp instead of a generator expression.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see any difficulty:

```
tuples = [   ('StemCells', 16.530000000000001),
    ('Bcells', 13.59),
    ('Monocytes', 11.58),
    ('abTcells', 10.050000000000001),
    ('Macrophages', 9.6899999999999995),
    ('gdTCells', 9.4900000000000002),
    ('StromalCells', 9.3599999999999994),
    ('DendriticCells', 9.1999999999999993),
    ('NKCells', 7.8099999999999996),
    ('Neutrophils', 2.71)]
print ', '. join('%s(%.02f)' % (name, value) for name, value in tuples)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
", ".join(["{0} ({1})".format(x[0], x[1]) for x in a])
```

Where `a` is your tuple.

*Explanation*

This uses a list comprehension and works as follows. The `for x in a` part iterates over your list, setting `x` to each element in turn so if you were to do:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [x for x in a]
print(b)
```

it would simply output your original list. In your case you want to combine the elements of your tuple at each stage. Since the first and second parts can be referred to with `[0]` and `[1]` it's a simple matter to extract them. The string `format` method can then be used to combine them:

```
a = Thimble
b = 1.234
print("{0} ({1})".format(a, b)
```

will print `Thimble (1.234)` since the `{0}` and `{1}` in the string get replaced by the arguments to the format method, putting these two parts together you get this:

```
a = [   ('StemCells', 16.530000000000001),
  ('Bcells', 13.59),
  ('Monocytes', 11.58),
  ('abTcells', 10.050000000000001) ]
b = ["{0} ({1})".format(x[0], x[1]) for x in a]
print(b)
```

Outputs:

```
['StemCells (16.53)', 'Bcells (13.59)', 'Monocytes (11.58)', 'abTcells (10.05)']
```

Finally, you can join the elements of a list together with your chosen separator using `join`, as follows:

```
", ".join(b)
```

This takes the string you're calling the method on and uses it as a separator when combining every element of the passed list, so in this case it will take each list element and combine them together with '`,`' between them and give you desired output:

```
StemCells (16.53), Bcells (13.59), Monocytes (11.58), abTcells (10.05)
```

Note that this is Python 3.3 but I believe it will also work in Python 2.7 and possibly earlier.

Comment: you can/should use a generator expression passing to join (i.e. get rid of the brackets)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [   ('StemCells', 16.530000000000001),
...     ('Bcells', 13.59),
...     ('Monocytes', 11.58),
...     ('abTcells', 10.050000000000001),
...     ('Macrophages', 9.6899999999999995),
...     ('gdTCells', 9.4900000000000002),
...     ('StromalCells', 9.3599999999999994),
...     ('DendriticCells', 9.1999999999999993),
...     ('NKCells', 7.8099999999999996),
...     ('Neutrophils', 2.71)]


>>> ['%s(%.2f)' % (f, d) for f,d in l]
['StemCells(16.53)', 'Bcells(13.59)', 'Monocytes(11.58)', 'abTcells(10.05)',
 'Macrophages(9.69)', 'gdTCells(9.49)', 'StromalCells(9.36)',
 'DendriticCells(9.20)', 'NKCells(7.81)', 'Neutrophils(2.71)']

>>> ', '.join(['%s(%.2f)' % (f, d) for f,d in l])
'StemCells(16.53), Bcells(13.59), Monocytes(11.58), abTcells(10.05), Macrophages(9.69), gdTCells(9.49), StromalCells(9.36), DendriticCells(9.20), NKCells(7.81), Neutrophils(2.71)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a list comprehension and python's string functions.

```
>>> s = [('StemCells', 16.530000000000001), ('Bcells', 13.59), ...]
>>> ", ".join(["{name}({num})".format(name=name, num=num) for name, num in s])
'StemCells(16.53), Bcells(13.59), Monocytes(11.58), abTcells(10.05), Macrophages(9.69), gdTCells(9.49), StromalCells(9.36), DendriticCells(9.2), NKCells(7.81), Neutrophils(2.71)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_str(lst):
    result = ""
    for i in lst:
        result += " {0}({1:.2f}), ".format(i[0], i[1])
    return result[:-2] if len(result) > 1 else result

a = [('StemCells', 16.530000000000001),
    ('Bcells', 13.59),
    ('Monocytes', 11.58),
    ('abTcells', 10.050000000000001),
    ('Macrophages', 9.6899999999999995),
    ('gdTCells', 9.4900000000000002),
    ('StromalCells', 9.3599999999999994),
    ('DendriticCells', 9.1999999999999993),
    ('NKCells', 7.8099999999999996),
    ('Neutrophils', 2.71)]
print make_str(a)
```

Output:

```
 StemCells(16.53),  Bcells(13.59),  Monocytes(11.58),  abTcells(10.05),  Macrophages(9.69),  gdTCells(9.49),  StromalCells(9.36),  DendriticCells(9.20),  NKCells(7.81),  Neutrophils(2.71)
```